# Como fazer nested tables com bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Como posso fazer nested tables com o bootstrap como [neste exempo com ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/308/)?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Há forma de fazer isso com bootstrap?

Comment: Jorge, não sei qual sua necessidade, linguagem e etc. Mas já deu uma olhada no [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). Tipo este exemplo: [Row Detail](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). Ele possui uma camada de configuração para Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @FernandoA.W. é só mesmo HTML com Bootstrap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assumindo o uso de `jQuery` pode fazer o seguinte:

```js
function esconderLinha(idDaLinha) {

    // procura o elemento com o ID passado para a função e coloca o estado para o contrario do estado actual
    $("#" + idDaLinha).toggle();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>

      </th>
      <th>
        Contact Name
      </th>
      <th>
        City
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button onClick="esconderLinha('linhaAEsconder')">
          +
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Berlin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="linhaAEsconder" style="display: none">
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                Order Id
              </th>
              <th>
                Date
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                10643
              </td>
              <td>
                8/25/1997 12:00:00 AM
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Funciona às mil maravilhas.

Answer (score 5):

No caso o Bootstrap requer jQuery, então você pode usar jQuery, apenas é preciso aportar o elemento com `$(...).next()`.

### Exemplo:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".mytable .open", function() {
    var tr = $(this).parents("tr").next();
    if (tr.hasClass("hide")) {
       tr.removeClass("hide"); 
    } else {
       tr.addClass("hide"); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>x</th>
            <th>y</th>
            <th>z</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn open">+</button></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">Sua sub tabela deve vir aqui</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn open">+</button></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">Sua sub tabela deve vir aqui</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn open">+</button></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">Sua sub tabela deve vir aqui</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Exemplo 2:

Automaticamente fecha os outros elementos `<tr>`:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".mytable .open", function() {
    var tr = $(this).parents("tr").next();

    if (tr.hasClass("hide")) {
       //Fecha todos outros tr antes de abrir o escolhido
       $(".mytable .subcontent").addClass("hide"); 

       //Abre o escolhido
       tr.removeClass("hide"); 
    } else {
       tr.addClass("hide"); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>x</th>
            <th>y</th>
            <th>z</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn open">+</button></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide subcontent">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">Sua sub tabela deve vir aqui</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn open">+</button></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide subcontent">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">Sua sub tabela deve vir aqui</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn open">+</button></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide subcontent">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">Sua sub tabela deve vir aqui</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```